# Could it improve search engine rankings to point custom domain names for targeted folders in WordPress?

Tags: seo, wordpress

I'm wondering if it may be a more effective SEO technique to have keyword-specific domain names point to a keyword-specific folder in WordPress than just have a file using the keyword.  Assume all other things being equal.

Here is an example to describe the question/issue that I am exploring. Assume a competitive landscape for the terms used.

Imagine a site with the domain usa.com that has folders named for states [california].

The objective is to get higher ranking for searches for "California" than otherwise might be the case.

Will using the domain california.com to point to a WordPress folder (california) within the site usa.com be effective?

Would this give the site california.com a higher rank than a page in the folder california named california.html?

If this makes sense, what would be the best way to implement it...or a substitute?

Comment: Oh for God's sake. No! Adding domain names do not solve problems nor do they do anything at all. As well, you cannot point a domain name to a directory. Only to a web space either by IP address or by CNAME. Anything else you would do would amount to squat. Search IS NOT about keywords and ranking for keywords. Period. So please stop thinking in those terms and just make an honest site that people like. Please! Thanks! Cheers!!

Comment: What you are proposing is called "exact match domains" (EMD) where you use a domain name with the exact keywords for which you are targeting to rank.   That technique was popular several years ago, but in 2012 Google cracked down on EMDs: https://searchenginewatch.com/2016/11/28/what-is-an-exact-match-domain-emd-and-why-does-google-want-to-punish-them/  Now they don't rank so well.